# Adjacent text styles (without spaces) in Redmine

Tags: markdown

I scoured Google and StackOverflow and was quite surprised that I couldn't find this question (and I apologize if I missed it).

Is there a Markdown syntax or escape mechanism allowing adjacent character sequences to be formatted using different text styles? For example, I can write `**bold** _italic_` for **bold** *italic*, and I can even write `**bold**_italic_` for **bold***italic* without the adjoining space. But most Markdown renderers I've used break down for longer sequences: `**bold**_italic_**bold**` does *not* give **bold***italic***bold**. (In fact, StackOverflow is the only place I've found where this works.) In general this seems even less reliable when mixing in monospaced styles using backticks.

In general, is there some way to delineate character sequences, maybe using some explicit construction like `{}` in LaTeX? E.g., something like `{**bold**}{_italic_}{**bold**}`?

It seems that implementations vary significantly in how they handle this. The question is whether there is a specific mechanism that can be used to delineate or scope formatting styles like the LaTeX `{}` mechanism.

Comment: I'm surprised by this: "But most Markdown renderers I've used break down for longer sequences: `**bold**_italic_**bold**` does not give **bold**_italic_**bold**. (In fact, StackOverflow is the only place I've found where this works.)" It works that way in lots of places, including on GitHub and on the original [Markdown dingus](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus). Can you give an example of this rendering differently?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above I'm surprised that you are having trouble with this. But in similar situations, e.g. to make *part* of a word italic, I have successfully taken advantage of Markdown's [inline HTML feature](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) by breaking the word up with a [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space): `&#8203;`.

For example, this:

```
_foo_&#8203;bar
```

renders like this:

*foo*​bar

This might help you as well, assuming your output format is HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In Redmine, you will have to use `<notextile></notextile>` in between two different formatted text to display them adjacently (without space).

Example:

**E**=mc<sup>2</sup>            will have to be `*E*=mc<notextile></notextile>^2^`.

As you may have observed, there are cases where even a simple bold cannot be displayed adjacently with a plain/unformatted text. The above example would shows a working scenario adjacent formatted and unformatted texts.

Here are the following formatting examples provided by Redmine's documentation of their [Textile formatting](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineTextFormattingTextile)

```
* *bold*
* _italic_
* *_bold italic_*
* +underline+
* -strike-through-
* Plain ^superscript^
* Plain ~subscript~
* @inline monospace@
* normal *bold* _italic_ normal;E=mc ^2^
* normal<notextile></notextile>*bold*<notextile></notextile>_italic_<notextile></notextile>normal;E=mc<notextile></notextile>^2^
* Escaping: <notextile>*bold* _italic_ @inlinemono@</notextile> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Alternative using HTML-codes: &#42;bold&#42; &#95;italic&#95; &#64;inlinemono&#64;
```

Result:

- **bold**
- *italic*
- **bold** *italic*
- <strike>strike though</strike>
- Plain <sup>superscript</sup>
- Plain <sub>subscript</sub>
- `inline monospace`
- normal **bold** *italic* normal;E=mc <sup>2</sup>
- normal**bold**​*italic*normal;E=mc<sup>2</sup>
- Escaping: *bold* *italic* @inlinemono@       Alternative using HTML-codes: *bold* _italic_ @inlinemono@

Answer (score 0):

I just checked on Redmine 3.4.8 and such Markdown syntax works as expected.

**bold**_italic_**bold**  -> **bold***italic***bold**